# Adding/updating dict with defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary

I know I can do the following to add/update a key in a dictionary in Python.

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(list)
mydict[x].append(y)
```

For my current situation, however, I'm trying to figure out how to use this functionality by adding an additional dict. I've done the following but it doesn't work as intended obviously.

```
mydict[x].append({'newKey': []})
mydict[x]['newKey'].append(100)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    mydict[x]['newKey'].append(100)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Is there a good way to use `defaultdict` to end up with a dictionary like so and continuously append to `newKey`?:

```
{
    x: {
        'newKey': [100]
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `mydict` look like after `mydict[x].append(y)` ?

Comment: mydict[x][-1][newKey].append(100)... note the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, right now you're trying to append a dictionary to mydict, so it seems like you should use `mydict = defaultdict(dict)`

Then you can do what you were trying:

```
In [2]: mydict = defaultdict(dict)
In [4]: mydict['x'] = {'newKey': []}

In [5]: mydict
Out[5]: defaultdict(dict, {'x': {'newKey': []}})

In [7]: mydict['x']['newKey'].append(100)

In [8]: mydict
Out[8]: defaultdict(dict, {'x': {'newKey': [100]}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing dict and list manipulation when you try to add your additional dict.

Some clarifications about your snippet:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(list)
x = 'x'
y = 'bar'
# getting mydict's field 'x'. As it does not exists, and 
# mydict is a default dict, this will create a key 'x' mapped 
# to the value [] and return it
mydict[x]
# so we retrieve the list mydict created for us and we add an element
# inside. Note that we're inserting y into a list
mydict[x].append(y)
# getting the same list and insterting another element inside
# mydict:
# {
# 'x' : ['bar', {'newKey': []}]
# }
mydict[x].append({'newKey': []})
# ...and that's why the following command will not work
mydict['x']['newKey'] # ERROR: mydict['x'] is a list and not a dict
```

You may have figured all that by yourself, now time for suggestions to solve it:

- use `defaultdict(dict)` to have non-existing entries be dict instead of lists
- use a more sophisticated initialization method:

```py
def init_entry():
    return {'newKey': [100]}
mydict = defaultdict(init_entry)
mydict['x']['newKey'].append(24)
mydict['y']['newKey'].append(37)
print(mydict)
#  {'x': {'newKey': [100, 24]}, 'y': {'newKey': [100, 37]}}
```

Comment: I like the custom initialization function idea. Sets it up for a more sophisticated, real-world use case.